# Wait loading web page until element is found

Tags: c#, winforms, browser, synchronous

I am new to c# and its concepts. I am trying to do some automation using the `winforms webbrowser control`.

I'm looking for a method that `loads a web page until a web item is found`.
To wait for the web page to load, I use line "Wait(30)"
"Wait(30)" this is an obvious expectation and this is not optimal.

I just need a `synchronous download`:
Find web item, if the web item is missing on the page then wait 1 second, if the web item is found finish downloading a web page.

Here is my code:

```
private void Wait(int number)
{
    DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
    do
    {
        Application.DoEvents();
    }
    while (time.AddSeconds(number) > DateTime.Now);
}

private void CheckFindElement1()
{
    try
    {
        Wait(30);
        var mlm = web_Browser.Document.GetElementById("id1");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Wait(1);
        CheckFindElement1();
    }
}
```

Comment: See the [WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx). Pair it with [WebBrowser.ReadyState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.readystate(v=vs.110).aspx) to verify that the current document is completed, then start the search for the elements you care about.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is very non productive. You should use the `WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted` event or you could use the `WebBrowser.ReadyState Property`.

```
private void CheckFindElement1()
{
   //This will go on untill the full page is loaded
    while (WebBrowser1.ReadyState.ToString() != "Complete") {
        Application.DoEvents();         
    }

   // Do your stuff here.
}
```